# Pandas - divide DataFrame values by a Series in a MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

Suppose I have a multi-index DataFrame such as this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['bucket 1', 'bucket 2'], ['q1', 'q2', 'q3']])
col = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), ix, col)
```

Output:

```
                 col1      col2      col3
bucket 1 q1  0.061384  0.364194 -1.502486
         q2  0.562352 -0.044836  0.242474
         q3  0.373411 -0.678429 -1.261984
bucket 2 q1  0.884109 -0.070899  0.085305
         q2 -0.010463  1.463259 -0.572882
         q3 -0.419821 -0.916151  0.032110
```

Now I create a Series with the index matching the columns of my DataFrame:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

I can divide the values in `bucket 1` in the DataFame by the Series like so:

```
df.loc["bucket 1"].div(s)
```

Output:

```
    col1      col2      col3
q1  0.061384  0.182097 -0.500829
q2  0.562352 -0.022418  0.080825
q3  0.373411 -0.339214 -0.420661
```

However if I try to use this calculation to set the values in the DataFrame using `.loc`, it just creates NaNs:

```
df.loc["bucket 1"] = df.loc["bucket 1"].div(s)
```

Output:

```
                 col1      col2      col3
bucket 1 q1       NaN       NaN       NaN
         q2       NaN       NaN       NaN
         q3       NaN       NaN       NaN
bucket 2 q1  0.884109 -0.070899  0.085305
         q2 -0.010463  1.463259 -0.572882
         q3 -0.419821 -0.916151  0.032110
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the calculations in the DataFrame?

Comment: Do you need to divide only one group by `s` or ultimately apply this to the entire `DataFrame`?

Comment: In my real use-case I will have a different Series to divide each bucket by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just Use `.values` to set the values:

```
df.loc["bucket 1"]=df.loc["bucket 1"].div(s).values
print(df)

                 col1      col2      col3
bucket 1 q1 -0.149856  0.220604 -0.048464
         q2 -0.791260 -0.199646  0.148115
         q3 -0.712257 -0.264074 -0.266497
bucket 2 q1 -1.120164 -0.290546  0.577589
         q2 -0.149522 -0.221203 -0.566872
         q3 -1.002036 -2.233220 -1.206849
```

Comment: Thanks! I find it very strange that to this day, you can't just replace a section of a DataFrame in-place. and you need `.values`.

Answer (score 2):

You just missing a `[]`

```
df.loc[["bucket 1"]]=df.loc[["bucket 1"]].div(s)
df
Out[1092]: 
                 col1      col2      col3
bucket 1 q1 -1.016733 -1.334495  0.417621
         q2  0.892984 -0.329325  0.224591
         q3  1.438399 -0.094883  0.053133
bucket 2 q1 -0.062476  0.962616  0.457755
         q2  0.389670  1.238829  0.390253
         q3  0.713873 -0.034645 -0.148381
```